# How Monsoon Season or Rainy Season (वर्षा ऋतू) has been described in Ancient scriptures of Hinduism?

Tags: vedas, scripture, culture

How  Rushies (ऋषी) , Poets (कवी) described Monsoon Season (वर्षा ऋतू)   in ancient Scriptures , shlokas , Subhasitas (सुभाषित) , Plays etc.?

Is there any description of Rainy season / Monsoon Season in "Vedas" (वेद) ?

Comment: Do you want only from Vedas or any other scriptures also be acceptable?

Comment: @Triyugi Narayan Mani , Not exclusively from vedas , but preferably from ancient scriptures. Any ancient form will do ,as I have mentioned like subhashitam , plays ,poems etc.

Comment: Ok. Its going to be very lengthy answer.

Comment: The first mention of season is in Purush Sukta of RigVeda... In verse 6 it states "6 When Gods prepared the sacrifice with Purusa as their offering, Its oil was spring, the holy gift was autumn; summer was the wood."

Comment: @Tezz , Triyugi Narayan Mani ,  also pls. add some scriptures in answers .I want the answer whith at least one sanskrit verse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rainy season is described in [Harivamsa Mahatmya](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_010.html), which is Khila of Mahabharata in details. The story is told by Sage Vaishampayan to Janmejay as below:

> vaishaMpAyana said:
>   (O janamejaya), after arriving at vR^indAvana, the two handsome sons of vasudeva wandered in the forest tending to calves.
>
> They completed the (remaining) summer time in the forest happily, playing with gopa-boys and bathing in the river yamunA.
>
> Then the rainy season lighting desires in the mind arrived. Great clouds adorned with rainbows (shakrachApa) on the belly, covered the sky and it started raining heavily.
>
> It was difficult to see the sun. The earth covered with grass was not visible. The earth appeared as if it regained youth since its surface was swept by strong winds spraying fresh water.
>
> The insects such as indragopakula drenched in the rain. The forest fires and the smokes were extinguished completely. The forest looked charming.
>
> It was the time for peacocks with large feathers to dance. The sounds of their joyful mingling could be heard everywhere.
>
> In the new rains, the trunks of young kadamba trees looked beautiful with the new clouds, providing food for butterflies and bees.
>
> The kuTaja and kadamba trees enhanced the beauty of the forest with their flowers and fragrance. The clouds destroyed the heat of summer. The earth was happy with rain water.
>
> The hills which were scorched by the sun rays and burned by blazing forest fires, breathed new life after being soaked with rain water.
>
> Strong winds blew everywhere. Huge clouds showered heavy rains. The earth, taken over by the sky, appeared like the city of a king. (strong winds blew like flags and huge clouds appeared like huge palaces of a king's city - nIlakaNTha).
>
> In some places, kadamba trees were in full bloom. In some other places, mushrooms flourished like ornaments. The forest appeared lit with nIpa flowers in full bloom.
>
> Drenched by indra's rain water, the fragrance of earth spread by winds, agitated the minds of people everywhere.
>
> The entire earth was filled with the sound of humming bees, croaking frogs and singing peacocks.
>
> Flowing forcefully with large whirlpools and abundant water obtained from the rains, the rivers increased their breadth uprooting trees from the banks.
>
> The birds with their wings wet in the heavy rain, refused to leave the tree tops as though they were exhausted.
>
> The sun was immersed in the bellies of the rain clouds, which were dense with water and rumbling with rain, in the sky.
>
> Covered with green grass and drenched in heavy rain, it became difficult to find paths which were indicated by the trees on both sides.
>
> The peaks of hills having trees whose top branches were cut as though struck by vajra, crumbled on the ground due to strong currents of water.
>
> The rain water from the clouds flowed through the land, according to the level. The low areas became full, flooding the forest.
>
> In the heavy rain, following the thunder of the clouds, wild elephants raised their heads, holding their trunks up. It appeared as though the clouds have descended on earth.
>
> Seeing that the rainy season has arrived and water bearing clouds have covered the sky, the son of rohiNi (balarAma) spoke these appropriate words to kR^iShNa.
>
> kR^iShNa, look at the dark clouds which are shining with groups of birds, as though decorated with ornaments. Stealing the colour of your body, they have gone up in the sky.
>
> This is the time for you to sleep. (It is known in purANA-s that viShNu sleeps during the four months of the rainy season -footnote on page 295, harivaMsha - gItA press). The sky has the colour of your body. In the rainy season, the moon remains incognito, like you.
>
> When the rainy season arrives, the blue sky appears black due to the presence of black rain clouds and shines like a blue lotus flower, as if bad days have come.
>
> See kR^iShNa, covered by the dark rain clouds, the govardhana hill which nourishes the cows, appears beautiful.
>
> Because of rain water, the black deer have become intoxicated. They appear happy as they roam in the forest.
>
> O lotus eyed one! Bathed by rain water, the new green grass is happily covering the earth fully with blades.
>
> Because of the arrival of rain clouds, there is no shortage of wealth (lakshmi) for the hills, the source of rivers, the forests and the land with plants.
>
> O dAmodara! The rain clouds, which induce people living in foreign lands to return home, forced by fast winds, roar loudly and show their pride.
>
> O hari who took the form of trivikrama! Without arrows and string, the tricoloured rainbow decorates your third foot (sky).
>
> The sun, the eye of sky, does not shine while moving in the sky (in the rainy season). The sun's heat producing rays are cooled by the clouds and it looks ray-less.
>
> The clouds shower incessant rain, spreading in the sky like a group of oceans. The clouds unite the sky with earth.
>
> Due to heavy rainfall on earth, the strong wind blows carrying the fragrance of the flowers of nIpa, arjuna and kadambA trees, stimulating the minds of people.
>
> It has started raining heavily. Big clouds have come closer to the earth. It looks as if the sky has merged with a deep and unlimited ocean.
>
> It looks as if the sky is getting ready for a battle, with a sword of rain, shield of lightning and a weapon of rainbow.
>
> O Handsome! (kR^iShNa)! The mountain peaks, the top of forests and the tree tops look enchanting, covered by dark clouds.
>
> The sky covered with dark clouds resembling a herd of elephants spraying water with their trunks, appears having the same colour as the ocean.
>
> The cool wind coming from the waves of the ocean is blowing carrying small drops of water, shaking the grass and keepers.
>
> Because of the water released by the rain clouds, the moon has disappeared in the night. The sun is drowned in the sky. The ten directions are not seen.
>
> The entire sky is alive with the clouds agitated by winds. The farmers are unable to differentiate between day and night.
>
> kR^iShNa! See vR^indAvanaM, devoid of the bad effects of heat and decorated by the water showered by the clouds, beautiful as the chaitraratha forest.
>
> hus glorifying the rainy season in vR^indAvana, kR^iShNa's mighty elder brother, returned to vraja.

Also there is a beautiful description of rainy season by great Kalidas in poem [Ritusamhar](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sha/sha18.htm), The Season.

> The rain advances like a king
>     In awful majesty;
>   Hear, dearest, how his thunders ring
>     Like royal drums, and see
>   His lightning-banners wave; a cloud
>     For elephant he rides,
>   And finds his welcome from the crowd
>     Of lovers and of brides.
>
> The clouds, a mighty army, march
>     With drumlike thundering
>   And stretch upon the rainbow's arch
>     The lightning's flashing string;
>   The cruel arrows of the rain
>     Smite them who love, apart
>   From whom they love, with stinging pain,
>     And pierce them to the heart.
>
> The forest seems to show its glee
>     In flowering nipa plants;
>   In waving twigs of many a tree
>     Wind-swept, it seems to dance;
>   Its ketak-blossom's opening sheath
>     Is like a smile put on
>   To greet the rain's reviving breath,
>     Now pain and heat are gone.
>
> To you, dear, may the cloudy time
>     Bring all that you desire,
>   Bring every pleasure, perfect, prime,
>     To set a bride on fire;
>   May rain whereby life wakes and shines
>     Where there is power of life,
>   The unchanging friend of clinging vines,
>     Shower blessings on my wife.

Also the rainy season is described in [Ramayana, Kishkindha Kand](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga28/kishkindha_28_frame.htm) by Sri Rama to Lakshmana during his `Chaturmas`. I am not providing all verses of though have linked the whole chapter.

> स तदा वालिनम् हत्वा सुग्रीवम् अभिषिच्य च |
>   वसन् माल्यवतः पृष्टे रामो लक्ष्मणम् अब्रवीत् || ३-२८-१
>
> Rama spoke to Lakshmana while residing on the mountainside of Mt. Malayavata, also known as Mt. Prasavana, ensuing the elimination of Vali and enthronement of Sugreeva. [3-28-1]
>
> अयम् स कालः संप्राप्तः समयो अद्य जल आगमः |
>   संपश्य त्वम् नभो मेघैः संवृतम् गिरि संनिभैः || ३-२८-२
>
> This is that time of which we thought and it has come to pass. Now it is rainy season. You see the sky fully covered with mountainous clouds. [3-28-2]
>
> नव मास धृतम् गर्भम् भास्कारस्य गभस्तिभिः |
>   पीत्वा रसम् समुद्राणाम् द्यौः प्रसूते रसायनम् || ३-२८-३
>
> Sustaining a nine-month pregnancy, impregnated through the Sun with his sunrays guzzling the essence of oceans, the heaven is giving birth to the elixir of life. [3-28-3]
>
> शक्यम् अंबरम् आरुह्य मेघ सोपान पंक्तिभिः |
>   कुटज अर्जुन मालाभिः अलंकर्तुम् दिवाकरम् || ३-२८-४
>
> It is very likely to climb up the flight of stairs of clouds to bedeck the sun with the garlands of white wild-jasmines, and red Arjuna flowers, in these days. [3-28-4]
>
> संध्या राग उत्थितैः ताम्रैः अंतेषु अधिक पाण्डुरैः |
>   स्निग्धैः अभ्र पट च्छेदैः बद्ध व्रणम् इव अंबरम् || ३-२८-५
>
> Those clouds with pure white edges, and with reddish hue of sunset extending on them, look like soft pieces of cloth bandaged on the gashes of sky. [3-28-5]
>
> मन्द मारुत निःश्वासम् संध्या चंदन रंजितम् |
>   आपाण्डु जलदम् भाति काम आतुरम् इव अंबरम् || ३-२८-६
>
> Slothful breezes as her sighs, sunset tingeing her as sandal paste, the sky with blanched clouds on her face appears like the one sighing for love. [3-28-6]
>
> एषा घर्म परिक्लिष्टा नव वारि परिप्लुता |
>   सीता इव शोक संतप्ता मही बाष्पम् विमुंचति || ३-२८-७
>
> Overly agonised with the searing-summer, but thoroughly wetted with new waters, this earth looks like Seetha, both implacably outpouring tears. [3-28-7]
>
> मेघ उदर विनिर्मुक्ताः कर्पूर दल शीतलाः |
>   शक्यम् अंजलिभिः पातुम् वाताः केतकि गन्धिनः || ३-२८-८
>
> Freed from the wombs of clouds, cool as the leaves of minty-camphor, perfumed with the fragrance of Mogra plants, such as these breezes are it is possible to have a draught of them with the bowl of palms. [3-28-8]
>
> एष फुल्ल अर्जुनः शैलः केतकैः अधिवासितः |
>   सुग्रीव इव शान्त अरिः धाराभिः अभिषिच्यते || ३-२८-९
>
> This mountain with fully bloomed Arjuna flowers, further fragranced by Ketaka flowers is being anointed with downpours on a par with Sugreeva, who is anointed when his enemy is silenced. [3-28-9]
>
> मेघ कृष्ण अजिन धरा धारा यज्ञ उपवीतिनः |
>   मारुत आपूरित गुहाः प्राधीता इव पर्वताः || ३-२८-१०
>
> Donning clouds as black deer skins, torrents as sacred-threads, and caves replete with breezes as vocals, the mountains look like young-scholars reciting Veda-s. [3-28-10]
>
> कशाभिः इव हैमीभिः विद्युद्भिः इव ताडितम् |
>   अन्तः स्तनित निर्घोषम् सवेदनम् इव अंबरम् || ३-२८-११
>
> While the flashes of lightning are whipping the sky as if they are the golden whips, it is letting out rattle of thunders holding out against its inly throes. [3-28-11]
>
> क्वचित् बाष्प अभिसंरुद्धान् वर्ष आगम समुत्सुकान् |
>   कुटजान् पश्य सौमित्रे पुष्टितान् गिरि सानुषु |
>   मम शोक अभिभूतस्य काम संदीपनान् स्थितान् || ३-२८-१४
>
> Feeling happy with the arrival of rain wild jasmine plants standing somewhere on the terraces of mountain are flowered, and they are thickly covered with droplets of vapour, as if they are the tears of happiness hovering round the flower like faces of ladyloves at the arrival of their lovers, and such plants are becoming inciters of passion in me, who am let down by my sorrow for my ladylove. [3-28-14]
>
> व्यामिश्रितम् सर्ज कदंब पुष्पैः
>   नवम् जलम् पर्वत धातु ताम्रम् |
>   मयूर केकाभिः अनुप्रयातम्
>   शैल अपगाः शीघ्रतरम् वहन्ति || ३-२८-१८
>
> Coalesced with Sarja and Wild-jasmine flowers, and also with the coppery ores of the mountain, the new waters are swiftly transiting towards ocean, while screams of peacocks haunting them. [3-28-18]
>
> वर्ष उदक आअप्यायित शाद्वलानि
>   प्रवृत्त नृत्त उत्सव बर्हिणानि |
>   वनानि निर्वृष्ट बलाहकानि
>   पश्य अपराह्णेषु अधिकम् विभान्ति || ३-२८-२१
>
> When clouds have completely rained on the greenery pasturelands are satiated with rainwater and peacocks are stimulated to dancing carnivals, thus it is extremely splendorous in afternoons, behold it. [3-28-21]
>
> वहन्ति वर्षन्ति नदन्ति भान्ति
>   ध्यायन्ति नृत्यन्ति समाश्वसन्ति |
>   नद्यो घना मत्त गजा वन अन्ताः
>   प्रिया विहीनाः शिखिनः प्लवंगाः || ३-२८-२७
>
> Rivers are surging, clouds are showering, rutty elephants are shrilling, forest interiors are shining, loverless are speculating, and peacocks are rocking, monkeys are resolving to stay at one place, for this is the rainy season. [3-28-27]
>
> नद्यः समुद्वाहित चक्रवाका
>   तटानि शीर्णानि अपवाहयित्वा |
>   दृप्ता नव प्राभृत पूर्ण भोगा
>   द्रुतम् स्व भर्तारम् उपोप यान्ति || ३-२८-३९
>
> Prideful rivers are swiftly surging near and near of their lover-like ocean overflowing their own battered riverbanks, and in doing so they are swinging and seesawing flights of ruddy gees flying on their bosom, where the curvatures of bird-flight look like the new, full-fledged, seducible, nubile breasts of the river, and in doing so the river is also lugging other items of romance, namely flowers and fruits, steeped in their new waters. [3-28-39]
>
> घन उपगूढम् गगनम् न तारा
>   न भास्करो दर्शनम् अभ्युपैति |
>   नवैः जल ओघैः धरणी वितृप्ता
>   तमो विलिप्ता न दिशः प्रकाशाः || ३-२८-४७
>
> Sky is closely enshrouded with clouds, neither sun nor stars are getting around for a glimpse, earth is fully satiated with the torrents of new water, enswathed in obscurity the precincts are unilluminated... [3-28-47]
>
> सुरताम् अर्द विच्छिन्नाः स्वर्ग स्त्री हार मौक्तिकाः |
>   पतन्ति च अतुलाः दिक्षु तोय धाराः समन्ततः || ३-२८-५१
>
> Like the strings of pearls of heavenly females plopping down when broken in the friction of lovemaking, excellent streams of water are falling all over and in all directions. [3-28-51]
>
> मासि प्रौष्ठपदे ब्रह्म ब्राह्मणानाम् विवक्षताम् |
>   अयम् अध्याय समयः सामगानाम् उपस्थितः || ३-२८-५४
>
> The month of Bhaadrapada, August-September, is the time for learning the singing of Sama Veda, and this is the time that has come for those Brahmans who concern themselves for learning the singing of Sama Veda. [3-28-54]

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Rainy season is mentioned in Vedas. It is considered the best season according to Chandogya Upanishad.

Chandogya Upanishad II.16.1(translated by Swami Gambhirananda)

> Spring is Himkara, summer is Prastava, **rains are Udgitha**, autumn is Pratihara, (early and late) winter is Nidhana. This Vairaja(Sama) is fully established on the seasons.