# Description of seasons in Hindu Scriptures

Tags: scripture, puranas

We know that environment has considerably changed comparatively to 20th century and is changing todays. We sometimes hear the discussion of our elders about systematic environments/seasons of 50-100 years before.

So, I just thought whether the description of seasons (viz. winter, summer & monsoon) had nicely described in any ancient scriptures? so-that we can get the imagination of seasons in ancient times!

I've found one related question: [How Monsoon Season or Rainy Season (वर्षा ऋतू) has been described in Ancient scriptures of Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13962/277)

So, How the seasons are described in Hindu scriptures?

Answer (score 6):

We find very detail and beautiful description of seasons in our **Puranic literature**. Shree **Vishnu Purana** and **Shreemad Bhagvatam** both dedicated several chapter’s about **beauty of various seasons** like Varsha Rutu (monsoon season) , Sharad Rutu etc.

We find **interesting** and **very fine details** about seasons in these Purnas .Like they are describing how **Sun ,Moon ,Clouds , Winds , Farmers ,Insects , Grass ,flowers**   were in those seasons , and how Shree Krishna himself enjoyed those seasons with his friends.

These are some of the verses from Shreemad Bhagvatam about Rainy Season and Autumn  seasons. The name of the chapter itself is “Description of Varsha and Sharad Rutu” [**Skanda 10, Chapter 20**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/20) **The Rainy Season and Autumn in Vṛndāvana**

> तत: प्रावर्तत प्रावृट सार्वसत्वसमूद्भव ।
>   विद्योतमानपरिधिर्विस्त्फुर्जितनभस्तला ॥3॥
>
> tataḥ prāvartata prāvṛṭ sarva-sattva-samudbhavā
>   vidyotamāna-paridhir visphūrjita-nabhas-talā
>
> Then the **rainy season** began, giving life and sustenance to all
>   living beings. The sky began to rumble with **thunder, and lightning**
>   flashed on the horizon.[**SB 10.20.3**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/20/3)
>
> ---
>
> सान्द्रनीलाम्बुदैर्व्योम सविद्युत्स्तनयित्नुभि:। 
>   अस्पष्टज्योतिराछ्चन्नं ब्रह्मेव सगुणं बभौ ॥4॥
>
> sāndra-nīlāmbudair vyoma sa-vidyut-stanayitnubhiḥ  
>  aspaṣṭa-jyotir
>   ācchannaṁ brahmeva sa-guṇaṁ babhau
>
> The **sky** was then covered by dense **blue** **clouds** accompanied
>   by lightning and thunder. Thus the sky and its **natural illumination
>   were covered** in the same way that the spirit soul is covered by the
>   three modes of material nature.[**SB 10.20.4**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/20/4)
>
> ---
>
> हरिता हरभि:
>   शष्पैरिन्द्रगोपेच्श्र लोहिता ।
>  उछ्हिलीन्ध्रकृतच्छया नृणा श्रीरिव
>   भूरभूत ॥11॥
>
> haritā haribhiḥ śaṣpair indragopaiś ca lohitā 
>   ucchilīndhra-kṛta-cchāyā nṛṇāṁ śrīr iva bhūr abhūt
>
> The **newly grown grass** made the earth emerald **green**, the
>   **indragopa** **insects** added a reddish hue, and white **mushrooms** added further color and circles of shade. Thus the earth appeared like
>   a person who has suddenly become rich.[**SB 10.20.11**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/20/11)
>
> ---
>
> खमशोभत
>   निर्मेघं शरद्वीम्लतारकं ।
>  सत्वयुक्तं यथा चित्तं
>   शब्दब्रम्हार्थदर्शनं ॥43॥
>
> kham aśobhata nirmeghaṁ śarad-vimala-tārakam
>  sattva-yuktaṁ yathā
>   cittaṁ śabda-brahmārtha-darśanam
>
> Free of clouds and filled with **clearly visible stars**, the
>   **autumn** sky shone brilliantly, just like the spiritual consciousness of one who has directly experienced the purport of the
>   Vedic scriptures.[**SB 10.20.43**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/20/43)
>
> ---
>
> आश्लिष्य समषितोष्ण
>   प्रसुनवनमारुतं। 
>  जनस्तापं जहुर्गोप्ये नकृष्णहृतचेतस:॥45॥
>
> āśliṣya sama-śītoṣṇaṁ prasūna-vana-mārutam
>  janās tāpaṁ jahur gopyo
>   na kṛṣṇa-hṛta-cetasaḥ
>
> Except for the gopīs, whose hearts had been stolen by Kṛṣṇa, the
>   people could forget their suffering by **embracing the wind** coming
>   from the **flower-filled forest**. This wind was **neither hot nor
>   cold**.[**SB 10.20.45**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/20/45)
>
> ---
>
> गावो मृगा: खगा नार्य: पुष्पिण्यः शारदा
>   भवन ।
>  अन्वियमाना: स्वव्रुषै: फ़लैरिषकिया इव ॥46॥
>
> gāvo mṛgāḥ khagā nāryaḥ puṣpiṇyaḥ śaradābhavan
>  anvīyamānāḥ
>   sva-vṛṣaiḥ phalair īśa-kriyā iva
>
> By the influence of the **autumn season**, all the cows, doe, women
>   and **female birds** became fertile and were followed by their
>   respective mates in search of sexual enjoyment, just as activities
>   performed for the service of the Supreme Lord are automatically
>   followed by all beneficial results. [**SB 10.20.46**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/20/46)
>
> ---
>
> we also find similar description in **Chapter 10 Vishnu purana** –( Sharad Varnanam and Govardhan puja शरद वर्णन ,गोवर्धन पूजा)
> [image]